# Basics of XML view in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I've been studying sapui5 framework for some time now and I always used javascript views in my applications.

The question is - are there reasons why should I prefer xml views over javascript, if I should do it at all? If there are some, what are they?

If I want to start trying to write xml views, what is the best place to learn the basic syntax and where can I find API reference for controls created using xml? The SAPUI5 [API](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html) is written for use with javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason I use XML views is because this is the standard approach of the Fiori apps by SAP. It creates a situation where developers only have 1 approach. Also to me they are easier readable.

Generally speaking I see that in the mobile library the xml views are used while in desktop usage js is still leading. On [SCN](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3641073) you can find many similar questions.

The library of [examples](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html) can be found in the same API page under tab EXPLORED.

Perhaps using the webIDE (which offers a local) install can provide a really good base for you to start development using xml based views.

Comment: To be complete, this is the link to [webIDE local trial version](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-58926)

Answer (score 3):

Major reason, in my view, is strict separation of concerns. XML views, by their nature, preclude code. Your XML view is therefore strictly presentation logic - a great outcome for professional enterprise development. It also reduces the significant lines of code to code out the ui and thus improves readability and maintenance of code.

Answer (score 2):

Where you say the API is written for js views, this is true because the controls are written in JavaScript. Look at it this way if you have a namespace in your xml like `xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"` any xml element prepended with l like `<l:GridData ...`
becomes a call to `sap.ui.layout.GridData` and if you look at the api for this control you can see what attributes you can add to this control / element.

Also if you have `xmlns="sap.m"` in your namespace block then anything like `<Page /> <Table />` become `sap.m.Page` or `sap.m.Table`  so the api is still a valuable resource and the explored section is great to see controls in action.

Comment: Yeah, but where can I learn the syntax of xml views? Like, take  that `<l:GridData...` for example. How do I know I have to write `l`? What does it mean? That `xmlns` thing - the same - what is that? when do I use it? Is there a guide for real newbs?

Comment: Most of the examples are written in xml in the explored section of the SDK site https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html
You can lookup controlls and then find full xml view / js controller code for each one. For real newbs start with the walkthrough: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html